# How do I test a PartialViewResult's object model that is returned from a Controller Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, ienumerable, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to write a unit test for the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult ProductList(int category)
{
    IEnumerable<Product> productList = repository.Products.Where(p => p.CategoryId == category);
    return PartialView("ProductList", productList);
}
```

and this is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<POS.Domain.Entities.Product>

@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_ProductSummary", p);
}
```

What I want to test is that given the int value `category`,  the `ProductList` action returns a `PartialView` with the appropriate values in `productList`.  I am not sure how to test the value of the `IEnumerable<Product> productList`.

Here is my unit test so far:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ProductListReturnsAppropriateProducts()
{
    // Arrange
    // - create the mock repository
    Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new Product[] {
    new Product {ProductId = 1, Name = "P1", CategoryId = 1},
    new Product {ProductId = 2, Name = "P2", CategoryId = 2},
    new Product {ProductId = 3, Name = "P3", CategoryId = 1},
    new Product {ProductId = 4, Name = "P4", CategoryId = 2},
    new Product {ProductId = 5, Name = "P5", CategoryId = 3}
    }.AsQueryable());

    // Arrange - create a controller
    ProductController controller = new ProductController(mock.Object);

    // Action
    IEnumerable<Product> result1 = (IEnumerable<Product>)controller.ProductList(1);
    //IEnumerable<Product> result2 = (IEnumerable<Product>)controller.ProductList(2); ???

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(result1, 2);
    // Assert.AreEqual(result2, 2); ???
}
```

I get a `System.InvalidCastException` because I am trying to cast a `PartialViewResult` to an `IEnumerable` - which is where I'm stuck.  **How do I target the IEnumerable `productList` in my controller for testing?**

Also, would it be bad practice to not test that the partial view is generated correctly?  (I am assuming that if the `productList` value is correct, the partial view will be rendered appropriately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that appears to cover what I need it to:

```
/// <summary>
/// Tests that the returned PartialViewResult contains the appropriate products for the selected category
/// First checks that the number of products is correct
/// Then checks that the number of products selected by a specific name is correct, to ensure that the Action did not
/// return products from different categories with the same Product.Name
///</summary>
[TestMethod]
public void ProductListReturnsAppropriateProducts()
{
    // Arrange
    // - create the mock repository
    Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new Product[] {
        new Product {ProductId = 1, Name = "P1", CategoryId = 1},
        new Product {ProductId = 2, Name = "P2", CategoryId = 2},
        new Product {ProductId = 3, Name = "P3", CategoryId = 1},
        new Product {ProductId = 4, Name = "P4", CategoryId = 2},
        new Product {ProductId = 5, Name = "P4", CategoryId = 3}
    }.AsQueryable());

    // Arrange - create a controller
    ProductController controller = new ProductController(mock.Object);

    // Action
    PartialViewResult result = (PartialViewResult) controller.ProductList(2);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(((IEnumerable<Product>)result.ViewData.Model).Count(), 2);
    Assert.IsTrue(((IEnumerable<Product>)result.ViewData.Model).Count(o => o.Name == "P4") == 1);
}
```

I was going to have several PartialViewResult values - but I began to have issues with testing multiple Controller Action results simultaneously.